# Understanding why this lemma is useful (Lindelöf's Lemma).

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In my real analysis class, the following lemma was presented to us:

**Lemma (Lindelöf):** Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$. Assume that for each $i\in I$, we have that $O_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ is open. If $A\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}O_i$, then there exists a countable $J\subseteq I$ such that $A\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in J} O_i$.

**Question:** Why is this lemma useful? The case where $J = I$ seems trivial to me and it's not talking about proper subsets $J\subsetneq I$. If you want to apply this lemma there's always the possibility that the lemma just holds for the trivial case, and you don't know anything new (I'm obviously mistaken).

Comment: The fact that $J$ is *countable* makes this lemma useful.

Comment: When you apply this lemma, it shows its usefulness.

Comment: @drhab Thanks, I completely missed the fact that an index set doesn't have to be countable!

Answer (score 2):

It is very useful for constructing an approximation of unity fo $A$, i.e. a fonction f such that $f|_A\equiv 1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $d(x,A)>\epsilon$. These kind of constructions are fundamental in differential geometry.